# exception when using time.strftime

Tags: python, ironpython

I've got a severe case of "works on my machine" :)

Consider the following simple code:

```
import time

t = time.strftime("%Y%m%d")
```

This code is deployed to a server with a share and 30 windows clients are started from there.
When running this from my machine it works but any other client gets the error

> IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException: No module named time

I fixed it by reverting to .NET DateTime

```
from System import DateTime
d = DateTime.Now
```

But i'd still like to know why the python version is not working. I'm using IronPython 2.7.5

Comment: https://ironpython-test.readthedocs.org/en/latest/library/time.html

Answer (score 0):

`time` is just a time object, no date.

```
>>> time?
Docstring:
time([hour[, minute[, second[, microsecond[, tzinfo]]]]]) --> a time object
```

`strftime` just provides formatting of this time object.

```
time.strftime?
Docstring: format -> strftime() style string.
```

Per the [docs](https://ironpython-test.readthedocs.org/en/latest/library/time.html), the `time` module provides various time-related functions. For related functionality, see also the datetime and calendar modules.

> Although this module is always available, not all functions are available on all platforms.

You are likely best off with:

```
import datetime as dt

t = dt.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d")
```